# Reduce size for HTML page with lots of duplicate code

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Noob question here, but I haven't found a straight answer for this elsewhere. I have a webapp written in Flask that on request generates a very large number of select boxes with the following code:

```
  {% for hour in hours %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ hour }}</td>
      {% for date in dates %}
        <td>
        <div id="select_{{ date }}_{{ hour }}" style="display:none;">
          <select name={{ "time" + "_" + date + "_" + hour }}>
              <option value="00" >{{ hour }}:00</option>
              <option value="15" >{{ hour }}:15</option>
              <option value="30" >{{ hour }}:30</option>
              <option value="45" >{{ hour }}:45</option>
          </select>    
          <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name={{ "value" + "_" + date + "_" + hour }}>
          {% for option in options %} 
            <option value="{{ option|safe }}" > 
                {{ option|safe }}
            </option>
          {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="plus_{{ date }}_{{ hour }}" style="display:block;">
          <a href="javascript:;show_select('{{ date }}', '{{ hour }}')" onClick="">+</a>
        </div>
        </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

where `dates` and `hours` obviously are lists with dates and hours, and  `options` is a list with a lot of options. All in all, my HTML document ends up being  more than 1 MB in size. What are my options if I want to reduce this size?

Thanks,
Filip

Comment: does your UX require a {hour} x {date} x {15min increment} view? think about using pagination, parent-child, or other pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this template to some JavaScript code and repeatedly do `document.write` or set the `innerhtml` property of different elements. In HTML5, you can use the [`template` tag](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/). Template support is provided by many libraries such as jquery, mustache, and so on, possibly implemented using the aforementioned techniques.

Comment: do use templating like mustache for this, but don't use document.write() for this